# URL myURL=MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);

Tags: java, utf-8, properties-file

The following code works fine if the property file in in class path but when I place property file in relevant package then its not reading it at all.

Here is my java code:

```
private String readPropVal(String propertyValue, String fileName)throws Exception{

    String path="";

    URL myURL = CategoriesMethods.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
    InputStream in = myURL.openStream();
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    Properties p = new Properties();

    p.load(new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
    path = p.getProperty(propertyValue);

    return path;    
}//
```

I guess following line is used to read the property file from class path:

```
URL myURL = CategoriesMethods.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

How can I use a path other than class path?

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which language this is, so we don't need to rely on other clues.

Comment: Please can you explain the problem in a little more detail. Editing your post title and adding language or framework specific tags would also be constructive, as it gives other users little to go on.

Comment: Preemptively guessing we're talking about Java here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code as below and its working perfectly

private String readPropVal(String propertyValue, String fileName)throws Exception{

```
    String path="";                             
        File propFile = new File(fileName);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(propFile),"UTF-8"));
        path = properties.getProperty(propertyValue);          
        return path;    
    }//
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a few modifications to your code to make it work. Seemes that you do not need to use the classLoader, but rather the class itself.

Also, my code now has a parameter **clazz**, which is the class the file is looked relative after - this way the code is more general, which I suppose is a good thing.

```
private String readPropVal(String property, String fileName, Class<?> clazz) {

    String value = "";

    URL myURL = clazz.getResource(fileName);
    if (myURL == null) {
        fileName = clazz.getResource(".").toString() + fileName;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName + " does not exist.");
    }
    Properties p = new Properties();

    try {
        p.load(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("problem reading file", e);
    }
    value = p.getProperty(property);

    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key \"" + property + "\" not found in " + myURL.toString());
    }

    return value;    
}
```

This method can now be called like this:

```
readPropVal("propertyName", "fileName.properties", AnyClassNextToTheFile.class)
```

Where **fileName.properties** file should contain a row like

```
propertyName = someValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately not works. Its throwing NPE by indicating this line p.load(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Improved the code to show better messages on problems.

Comment: even then its not working. I reshaped my code and posted above. Now my code is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Mikk from the bottom of my heart for giving me your precious time